# Bluebird, promises and then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've been only using bluebird for a few days but I want to go over all my old code and `promisify` it :)

My problem is that I still don't fully grasp the flow of `then()` commands.

Consider these two blocks:

A

```
methodThatReturnsAPromise().then(task2).then(task3);
```

B

```
var promise = methodThatReturnsAPromise();
promise.then(task2)
promise.then(task3);
```

1. in scenario A `task3` will get the result of `task2`? In B they all get the result of the first promise?
2. How does the second one differ from running `Promise.all` from bluebird?
3. How do these A/B/`Promise.all` differ when it comes to using the `catch` method (where do I put it).

Sorry it's a bunch of questions in one.

Comment: How would you run `Promise.all`?

Comment: @Bergi https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promiseallarraydynamicpromise-values---promise this is `.all`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I know well what it does, I asked the OP how he would apply it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of promises.

#### How `then` works in your example

Your assertion in `1` is correct. We can simulate a promise resolving in Bluebird using `Promise.resolve` on a value.

Let's show this:

Let's get a function that returns a promise:

```
function foo(){
    return Promise.resolve("Value");    
}

foo().then(alert);
```

This short snippet will alert `"Value"` as [we can see](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ep9x/).

Now, let's create two more promises, each that alert and return different values.

```
function task2(e){
    alert("In two got " + e);
    return " Two ";
}
function task3(e){
    alert("In three got " + e);
    return " Three ";
}
```

So, as you can see in [your first code](http://jsfiddle.net/4sA99/) it will indeed resolve in a chain, each with the value of the previous part.

In the second example, both task2 and task3 will get the same value and will also execute together (that is, task 3 will not wait for task 2). You can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E6pF4/).

#### Promise.all

Promise.all (or just returning an array from a `then` fulfillment handler and then using `.spread`) is used for waiting for multiple results to all complete. On your example, you're hooking on a single result in multiple parts.

#### The catch

You always put catch where you want the error to be caught. As you would normally in synchronous code. Just remember to always throw in a promise or in promisified code.

Comment: so I can put the catch anywhere on the chain and it will catch any propagated errors? If I rethrow anywhere along the chain I can recatch it later?

Comment: @Madd0g yes. Exactly like you would with normal try/catch blocks.

Comment: Awesome. I think I tried to catch a rethrown error before and it didn't work, but it might have been my fault, I'll try again. Thanks for the great answer

Answer (score 12):

> in scenario A task3 will get the result of task2? In B they all get the result of the first promise?

Yes.

> How does the second one differ from running Promise.all from bluebird?

You do not fetch the results of the (parallel) tasks 2 and 3 into a new promise.

> How do these A/B/Promise.all differ when it comes to using the catch method (where do I put it).

Usually you would put it on the end of the chain, except you want to catch a specific error.

```
promise.catch()
// handles rejections of this promise

promise.then(task2).catch()
// handles rejections from either promise or task2
// if promise is rejected, task2 will not be executed

Promise.all(promise.then(task2), promise.then(task3)).catch()
// handles rejections from any.
// if promise is rejected, neither task2 nor task3 will be executed
// if task2 or task3 throw, the error will immediately handled
// and the other task will not be affected (but its result is unavailable)
```

Comment: I guess I did mostly understand how it works. Very intuitive, I wish I could go back in time and erase the few months I've spent fighting callbacks and pyramids :) Thanks for the answer. I'll award the answer to the other guy, because he was a bit quicker and did those great jsfiddles, but have an upvote instead - great answer

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting one simple principle **chaining**

In first one can be written like

> ```
> var promise   = methodThatReturnsAPromise(),
>     promise1  = promise.then(task2);
> promise1.then(task3);
> ```

In second case

> ```
> var promise   = methodThatReturnsAPromise();
> promise.then(task2)
> promise.then(task3);
> ```

Hope this explains the difference b/w the two